# After uploading my game to Play Store, it increases in size and crashes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

As of August 2nd, the Play Store requires apps to be uploaded via .aab files with Play Asset Delivery instead of .obb extension files for apps bigger than 150MB.

I am building a 2D game in the latest version of Unity. I followed [this guide here](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-unity) to get an .aab file that can be uploaded to the Play Store for my internal testing.
The .aab file that I get as output weighs 300MB, which seems already strange to me, as the .apk file I get if I ask Unity to output an APK weighs only 200MB.

But an even weirder thing happens when I successfully add the .aab as a new release on the Play Console: when I try to install the game from the Play Store it weighs 1 entire GB! And the game crashes as soon as I open it.

Do you have any idea on what I might be doing wrong in the process?

Comment: May not fix your problems fully but have you checked your graphics. As an example the .png files is stored as 2048 as standard and you could string them and by that saving some space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by removing the Play Core plugin I was using to build the .aab and using the default method from Unity's Build Settings (instructions [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/play-asset-delivery.html?_gl=1*1htjpxs*_ga*MTY0MjU2NzM4MS4xNjA1NTM3NjQ1*_ga_1S78EFL1W5*MTYyODc5NjU0Mi44OS4xLjE2Mjg3OTY2NTMuNTg.&_ga=2.106666371.1697828815.1628796544-1642567381.1605537645)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a compression problem with your assets? Again, we dont have much info about what your project has in terms of assets etc. A mobile game/app with a 300mb build smells like you're using non-mobile-ready assets e.g. high-poly models or many HD textures?

I would recommend using the unity profiler to further look into this...